# What is a valedictorian

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

I found in a dictionary that valedictorian is the student who gives a speech at a graduation ceremony. I that the only word for that?

Comment: In what dictionary was *valedictorian* defined as as the student to give a speech at a graduation ceremony?

Answer (score 1):

The

> **valedictorian**

is considered the *top student* of the graduating class.

They can be one of several

> **commencement speakers**

who are specifically there to address the graduating class and participate in the ceremony.